How do I modify the test dir for pytest with dev containers?
I'm using dev containers and I want to set the "python.testing.cwd" field in my non-committed .code-workspace file.
It seems like the setting is totally ignored. If I set it in .code-workspace or .vscode/settings.json tests are still discovered from the root.
If I set "python.testing.cwd" in the devcontainer json config it does seem to use it. But I don't want that.
Why is my dev container ignoring my pytest settings in my other configs?
